# Export table1 with relations to table3 through table2 with reseted id;

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables needs to export as .sql for future imports. The main table i need to export has relations to a table through an other one table. You can see a synopsis of schema bellow:

[image]

Main problem is that id to each of the tables doesn't start at 1 as expected because a lot of test inputs on development stage.

To this example, is it possible to export in a .sql file images table including relations(image_tags, tags) with reseted id to images and so on for the other tables but keep the relations acording to new id?

Comment: Why exactly is _".. id to each of the tables doesn't start at 1"_ a problem?

Comment: There are work around but as Nae asked, what issue you are facing for ids not started from 1?

Comment: Assume i add 3 rows to Images and then delete them,  when i add the correct images to table the id starts from 4. i need to export but make the id again start to 1.

Comment: there should have no issue if you keep the id started from 4, right?

Comment: Right, its works fine. The reason i want to fix it when i import that to other database is to be more human readable with no numbers missing from id eg row1.id => 3 row2.id => 4 row3.id => 17 ...

Comment: Yup got your point. There is nothing automatic process. You need some manual script execution to update data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not do anything from below in your current/LIVE database. As you said you wants to export data to other database, apply this following steps to the other database-

Step-1: Get ready with your new database with data from your LIVE database.

Step-2: Add 2 new column "image_id_new" and "tag_id_new" to the table "images_tags".

Step-3: Execute these following 2 script to updated newly created 2 columns-

> Before execute below scripts, please make sure there are no 0 value available in either column "image_id" and "tag_id"

```
UPDATE images_tags A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT image_id,
    @row_num := IF(`image_id` <> 0,@row_num+1,0)AS RowNumber     
    FROM images_tags,
    (SELECT @row_num := 0) r
    ORDER BY image_id
)B ON A.image_id = B.image_id
SET A.image_id_new = RowNumber;

UPDATE images_tags A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT tag_id,
    @row_num := IF(`tag_id` <> 0,@row_num+1,0)AS RowNumber   
    FROM images_tags,
    (SELECT @row_num := 0) r
    ORDER BY tag_id
)B ON A.tag_id = B.tag_id
SET A.tag_id_new = RowNumber;
```

Step-4: Please remove relations (If Any) between tables Images>>Images_Tags>>Tags.

Step-5: Now update all three tables using these following scripts-

```
UPDATE images A INNER JOIN images_tags B ON A.id = B.image_id
SET A.id = B.image_id_new;

UPDATE tags A INNER JOIN images_tags B ON A.id = B.tag_id
SET A.id = B.tag_id_new;

UPDATE images_tags
SET image_id = image_id_new,tag_id = tag_id_new;
```

Step-6: Remove both new columns from table images_tags with the following script-

```
ALTER TABLE `images_tags` 
DROP COLUMN `tag_id_new`,
DROP COLUMN `image_id_new`;
```

Step-7: Re establish the relations between tables Images>>Images_Tags>>Tags if required.

That's it. Hope this will help.

Comment: For the first row the id goes to 1 but for the other sometimes skipping numbers. Also, i cannot change id column to images because its primary key. By the way, is not so big problem to leave it as it is. Thanks,